# Spring boot many to one mapping error when updating object

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on spring boot and using many to one relationship like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "media_files")
public class Media {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "media", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
  private Set<MediaUser> users = new HashSet<>();

  ....

}
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
 private Set<MediaUser> users = new HashSet<>();
 ....
}
```

MediaUser

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "media_to_users")
public class MediaUser implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "media_id")
   private Media media;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;


  @JsonBackReference
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Media parent;
  .....
 }
```

And I add new entiry like this

```
media.getUsers().add(new MediaUser(media, user, parent));
```

Which works fine however if I try to update I get error

```
//Get media from db
Media media = mediaRepository.getOne(id);
//clear already existing entries
media.getUsers().clear();


   String[]  users = {"3","2"};
    for (String userIdStr: users) {
        User user = userRepository.getOne(Long.parseLong(userIdStr));
        if(user != null){
             media.getUsers().add(new MediaUser(media, user, null));
            //mediaUserSet.add(new MediaUser(media, user, null));
        }
    }

 mediaRepository.save(media);
```

Error is:

```
  java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_id' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
```

Comment: Have you created the user1 and user2 record in database before using in MediaUser update ? Only when it is created in database user id is assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are passing `user1, user2` as not persisted entities.

You either need to persist them before the save of `media` or add cascading to the annotation:

```
 @Id
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
 private User user;
```

You also need to make sure that if `User` has a `@OneToMay` relation to `MediaUser` you have to add those users to the collection.

```
String[]  users = {"3","2"};
for (String userIdStr: users) {
    User user = userRepository.getOne(Long.parseLong(userIdStr));
    if(user != null){
        MediaUser mediaUser = new MediaUser(media, user, null) 
        user.getUsers().add(mediaUser);
        media.getUsers().add(mediaUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Maciej, Thanks. just added changes but still same issue. Updating changes in question.

Comment: Can you add User class to question ass well as how you create / retrieve user1 and user2?

Comment: Try to follow my last sentence. You do not populate that collection. So user.getUsers().add(mediaUser);

Comment: I did not get it. Could you please show an example. I spent a whole day on this. Really need help.I am trying to understand more what did you mean.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187809/discussion-between-vk321-and-maciej-kowalski).

Comment: now i get error  A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance:

Comment: Updated once more

Comment: Thank you!! Now I have error: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session :

Comment: you need to use merge instead of save / persist then

Comment: how do i do that there is no mediaRepository.merge() method on jpa.